# ¿Por qué esta fallando al llamar el conjunto Array pero de manera individual no en PHP?

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Estaba teniendo problemas con el código que estoy escribiendo entonces quise comprobar que imprimía la variable array. Al llamar la variable que contiene array devuelve "array" en texto pero si llamo los valores de manera individual funciona bien, ¿como es eso? ¿como funciona?

```
$bind = array();
$bind [0] = "a";
$bind [1] = "0";

echo $bind [0], $bind [1]; // esto imprime bien: a0
echo $bind; // esto  no: Array
```

He intentado un for como este pero simplemente devuelve 01 (los valores de $bind [0] i $bind [1]:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($bind); $i++) {   
  echo($bind[$i] + ",");
}
```

Tambien habia probado `print_r($bind)` pero no devuelve nada.

Por si sirve de algo, la intencion es lammar el array en bind_param de MYSQLI

```
$resultado->bind_param("$string", $bind);
```

Comment: Conceptualmente no puedes imprimir un Array directamente, ya que es un conjunto de elementos. Tendrías que saber cómo imprimir cada elemento, el señarador, si quieres un formato en concreto... Eso debes definirlo tu . La salida que tienes es correcta

Comment: como dices lo he intentado con el for y algunas mas pero no lo consigo, es que tengo el for mal o como lo hago?

Comment: Ese bucle forma debería devolverte "a,0,"  y no "01" como mencionas. Viendo tu for, parece que quieres crear una cadena a partir del Array. Puedes hacerlo con "implode(',',$bind);" busca esta función en la documentación de php

Comment: El problema del for es que estas sumando `+` por lo que se realiza una conversión a int. El operador de concatenación en PHP es el punto `.` no el símbolo más `+`. El echo debería ser algo asi: `echo $bind[$i] . ",";` . Los paréntesis no son necesarios.

Comment: Gracias Jakala i Xerif, el resultado que buscaba era el del implode que devuelve sin una coma final a diferencia del for que como dice Xerif con el punto funciona. Aunque cuando lo la variable del implode dentro del bind_param no funciona... pero gracias por resolver la pregunta. Le he dado dos veces para hacer tu comentario como que ha sido de ayuda Jakala pero como la segunda te lo he quitad ya no me deja volvértelo a dar lo siento.

Answer (score 0):

Para ver el contenido del array en conjunto puedes utilizar

```
var_dump($bind);
```

que te devolvera:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

Comment: lo he intentado y da error (es el único que me hace saltar error), gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No es posible imprimir un array con echo porque solo imprime cadenas, la variable `$bind` es un array de cadenas que no es lo mismo. Para poder imprimirlo debes convertir el array a una cadena:

```
// forma 1
echo "<pre>".print_r($bind,true)."</pre>";
// forma 2
echo implode(", ",$bind);
// forma 3 (sin echo)
var_dump($bind);
```